# Not able to left justify a DropDownListFor

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an Html.DropDownListFor with BootStrap that is not left justifying like the Html.TextBoxFor in my form. I've tried both the "pull-left" and "text-left" with no luck. When I look at page with the Developer Tools there doesn't look to be anything that I can see causing a problem.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Submitter Information</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="row form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmployeeId, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label text-right" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeId, new { @class = "col-md-8 form-control", @readonly = "true" })
        </div>

        <div class="row form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmployeeName, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label text-right" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeName, new { @class = "col-md-8 form-control", autofocus = true, @placeholder = "Employee Name" })
        </div>

        <div class="row form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmployeeEmail, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label text-right" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeEmail, new { @class = "col-md-8 form-control", @placeholder = "Email Address" })
        </div>

        <div class="row form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedEmployeeCo, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label text-right" })
            <div class="col-md-8 pull-left">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedEmployeeCo, 
                                        new SelectList(Model.Companies, "Co", "Name"), 
                                        "-- Select Company --", 
                                        new {@class = "form-control text-left" })
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What if you add "form-control" on the div? `<div class="col-md-8 pull-left form-control">`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that didn't work but it got me looking at it with a fresh set of eyes this morning and I figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some things around and this should have been obivious to me since I was doing the same thing for the other TextBoxFor. I ended up moving the column class into the CSS directly on the DropDownListFor instead of in a separate div. I would have thought it would render the same but it doesn't. So, the point here is to be consistent. Either wrap each control in a div with the column CSS or apply the CSS directly on the control.

This is how I fixed it.

```
<div class="row form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedEmployeeCo, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label text-right" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedEmployeeCo,
                            new SelectList(Model.Companies, "Co", "Name"),
                            "-- Select Company --",
                            new { @class = "col-md-8 form-control pull-left" })
</div>
```